# Unterminated String error while iterating

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code :

```
<c:forEach items="${entry.value}" var="keyval">
 var bdgroup= {
   elem1: '${keyval.partno}',
   elem2: '${keyval.location}',
   elem3: '${keyval.village}',
   elem4: '${keyval.id}'
   };
   exampleArray.push(bdgroup);
</c:forEach>
```

i am getting

'unterminated string literal error'`

sometimes it works fine but for other times this error happens..

Comment: Mark has answered this, but I don't like that you are re-declaring bdgroup over and over. One way to quickly remove that is to say: exampleArray.push({elem1:'expr',elem2:'expr',...}); with proper white space it should be just as easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

When e.g. `${keyval.id}` gets expanded, if it has a single quote in it, then the Javascript will look like

```
elem1: 'what's up?'
```

thus your unterminated string error.

Escape the quotes before you put them in JSON.

Comment: exactly what i had seen in the console..i tried this..var villa='${keyval.id}'.replace(/'/g, "''"); but this also failing..how can i escape it?

Comment: @sakar you need to replace it inside the braces.  I'm not sure what tool you're using for that, but it should be more like `'${keyval.id.toEscapedString()}'`.

Comment: this is not possible to replace in javascript..as per your idea, i replaced it on server side ..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a taglib, and the elements inside the single quotes are being generated by the page processor.

I'll bet that on the times that it fails, your values contain single quotes.

Escape the single quotes, and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the single quotes and any other special characters, so that the values are taken correctly.

I'm ==> I\'m